# Can't enter password using Java ProcessBuilder to interact with a CLI

Tags: java, linux, jboss, command-line-interface

I'm trying to interact with a CLI on a server from a web browser. On the server side, I'm using a Java Servlet running on JBoss AS 7.1.1.Final. The CLI is an ovirt-engine tool ([ovirt-iso-uploader](https://github.com/oVirt/ovirt-iso-uploader)). In order to use it, you have to provide the REST API password when it requests it.

Therefore, here is the following code I'm using to interact with the CLI:

```
private String executeCommand(String command) {

    System.out.println("Executing command: " + command);

    String[] commands = new String[]{"/bin/sh","-c",command};

    try {
        ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder(commands);
        builder.redirectErrorStream(true);
        Process p = builder.start();

        BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(p.getOutputStream()));
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));

        String line = "";

        while ((line = reader.readLine())!= null) {
            System.out.println(line);

            if (line.contains("Please provide the REST API password")){
                writer.write( "password\n" );
                writer.flush();

            }

        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

    }
}
```

However, whatever input command I'm using, I always have the same problem. (For this example I used the command `ovirt-iso-uploader list` to list all the ISO storage domains. You can find the documentation of the CLI [here](https://github.com/ovirt-china/iso-uploader-plugin/wiki/CLI-Documentation))

```
11:31:34,282 INFO  [stdout] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-2) Executing command: ovirt-iso-uploader list
Please provide the REST API password for the admin@internal oVirt Engine user (CTRL+D to abort):
```

So the execution is blocked here as the CLI is waiting for the password and the Servlet can't see the line `Please provide the REST API password for the admin@internal oVirt Engine user (CTRL+D to abort):` as it is not send in `[stdout]`. However, it is working if I manually enter the password directly in the terminal.

Therefore, my question is how can I read the password request from the CLI and answer to it ?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: You might want to check for libraries that resemble "expect" functionality, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6394836/ssh-in-java-app-with-expect-like-functionality ... doing this yourself using only the "built-in" capabilities of Java might turn out to be **hard**

Comment: Are you sure that your if condition is true? Can you put a println inside it to confirm it?

Comment: @Jägermeister thanks I will have a look. However, do you have any idea why the password request is not in `[stdout]` ?

Comment: @assylias the if condition is never true because the Servlet never read the password request. Therefore `line` never contains the sentence : `Please provide the REST API password for the admin@internal oVirt Engine user (CTRL+D to abort):` That is the thing I don't understand.

Comment: Having this exact problem (where I'm running svn command and need to enter password). Did you ever find out the reason for this? and how did you deal with it?

Comment: same problem! did u find any solution?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that buffered reader is the wrong thing to use as it may be waiting for a newline at the end of the prompt which is not there and can not therefore return a line.

I think you will have to read the stream directly. Maybe character by character or byte by byte.

It may also not be necessary to wait for the prompt. In unix shell programming it is common to provide the standard input without reference to prompt like:

```
Command <!
Lineone
line two
!
```